# Ocultar carpetas de la URL usando .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

he intentado usando .htaccess ocultar dos carpetas de la barra URL del navegador, y que solo se tenga que poner el nombre del archivo vista

Para eso use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ resources/view/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.view.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.view.php [NC]
```

El problema es que no me sale, me trata el archivo vista como si fuera un directorio de carpetas:

[image: Problema]

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: Estructura]

Ahora, lo que yo busco es que la URL me ignore las carpetas resources/view/ y que al poner el nombre del fichero en la URL me muestre la vista. Como en la imagen que postee primero arriba en la URL se ve que puse "php.devel.com/prueba/php_pruebas/blog/perfil" esa URL debe mostrarme la vista perfil.view.php.

También he configurado .htaccess para que me ignore las extensiones de los ficheros .view.php o .php, es por eso que solo puse perfil sin las extensiones en la URL

Comment: Hola, deberías añadir algo más de detalle a la pregunta: ¿cuál es la estructura de directorios/ficheros  en tu proyecto? ¿cómo se leen  los ficheros redirigidos en tu proyecto? ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de la URL que falla  (qué es lo que muestra y qué es lo  que  debería mostrar)? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Listo, lo edite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta configuración funciona en un servidor virtual que apunta a la carpeta `public_html`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/www/test/public_html"
    ServerName test.localhost.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-access_log" common
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/www/test/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
#    LogLevel rewrite:trace4
</VirtualHost>
```

Nota: Descomentando la linea de `LogLevel` se puede ver en el log de errores como apache resuelve los rewrites.

El `.htaccess` está en el `public_html`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase "/"
  RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" ^\/(.+)$
  RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/resources/view/%1.view.php" -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ resources/view/%1.view.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

La primera condición es para obtener en `%1` el request uri sin el `'/'` inicial.
La segunda condición verificar el request uri sin el `'/'` inicial existe como archivo `.view.php` dentro del document root del servidor virtual en la subcarpeta `resources/view`.

Si ésta condición se cumple hace el rewrite de la url.

La estructura donde se probó:

```
public_html
  |_ resources
  |     |_ view
  |         |_ index.view.php
  |         |_ perfil.view.php
  |_ index.php
  |_ .htaccess
```

Invocando `http://test.localhost.com/perfil` muestra el contenido de `resources/view/perfil.php`. Lo mismo con `index`.

Comment: También he intentado creando el mismo host virtual que tu posteaste y copiando el .htaccess, me sigue sin reconocer el fichero

Comment: En mi caso el fqdn del ServerName lo configuré en /etc/hosts de forma que pingueando test.localhost.com resuelva a la ip donde está escuchando el webserver. Osea http://test.localhost.com debería abrir el index.php que está en la raíz. ¿Esto lo tenés igual?

Comment: Mi error, hice el host virtual que posteaste  y lo probe, si funcionó, lo probe en mi host virtual y tambien. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas *capturar* el nombre de la vista:

`RewriteRule .*/(.*)$ resources/view/$1.view.php [L]`

La directiva `RewriteCond` es únicamente para saber si se evalúa la regla, por lo cual no siempre es necesaria.

Comment: Cuando intento capturar el archivo vista me sale como objeto no encontrado en el navegador